# Cannot read property '706142720527171634' of undefined. discord music bot crashes

Tags: node.js, discord.js

My bot has a skip and stop commands it gives this error when I try that command

> Cannot read property '706142720527171634' of undefined
> I also re-wrote the code,
> These are the two commands' codes

```
if(msg.content === 'r!' + 'skip'){
  server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0],{filter: "audioonly"}));
  var server = servers[msg.guild.id];
  if (server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
}
if(msg.content === 'r!' + 'stop'){
var server = server[msg.guild.id];
if(msg.guild.voice.connection){
  for(var i = server.queue.length -1; i >=0; i--){
    server.queue.splice(i, 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you used `server` instead of `servers`: `server[msg.guild.id];`.
The following should work:

```js
if(msg.content === 'r!' + 'skip'){
  server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0],{filter: "audioonly"}));
  var server = servers[msg.guild.id];
  if (server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
}
if(msg.content === 'r!' + 'stop'){
var server = servers[msg.guild.id];
if(msg.guild.voice.connection){
  for(var i = server.queue.length -1; i >=0; i--){
    server.queue.splice(i, 1);
  }
```